# how to clear a variable's value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

After clicking `print` button a receipt is shown with a set of values in a modal using javascript. After closing the screen while click again `print` button a receipt is shown in the modal with previous values.

I want to reset that variable values when the modal is closed.

**modal**

```
 <div class="modal" id="printModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body" id="print-modal">        
        <div id="invoice-POS">                                
            <center id="top">
              <div class="logo">
                <img src="{{URL::asset('assets/img/logo/logo.jpg')}}" alt="Wooden Oven" width="80px" height="60px">
              </div>
            </center><!--End InvoiceTop-->            
            <div id="mid">
                <div class="info">
                    <h1>Order : <span id="orders_id"></span></h1>
                    <p>
                        Branch : <span class="order-info" id="branch_name"></span></br>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div id="bot">
                    <div id="table">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--End Invoice Mid-->
        </div><!--End Invoice-->      
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary print-invoice">print</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
table = '<table>';
table += '<tr class="tabletitle"><td class="item"><p><b>Item</b></p></td><td class="text-align-right"><p><b>Qty</b></p></td><td class="text-align-right"><p><b>Rate</b></p></td><td class="text-align-right"><p><b>Total</b></p></td></tr>';
table += '<tr class="tabletitle"> <td class="text-align-right" colspan="3"><p><b>Grand Total :</b></p></td><td class="text-align-right"><p>'+data['orders'][0].total_amount+'</p></td></tr>';
table += '<tr class="tabletitle"> <td class="text-align-right" colspan="3"><p><b>Discount :</b></p></td><td class="text-align-right"><p>'+data['orders'][0].discount+'</p></td></tr>';
table += '<tr class="tabletitle"> <td class="text-align-right" colspan="3"><p><b>Net Receivable Amount :</b></p></td><td class="text-align-right"><p>'+data['orders'][0].net_receivable_amount+'</p></td></tr>';
table += '<tr class="tabletitle"> <td class="text-align-right" colspan="3"><p><b>Paid Amount :</b></p></td><td class="text-align-right"><p>'+data['orders_paid_amount'][0].paid_amount+'</p></td></tr>';
table += '</table>';
$('#table').append(table);
delete table;
$('#printModal').modal('show');
```

I have used `delete table`. But it's not working.

Anybody help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: You appended your html, so it's too late, you need to remove the html from '#table', like so : `$('#html').empty()`, and you need to do it before appending again

Comment: @Lk77.... yes it's working !! Please post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: My advice would be to make use of a `<template>` HTML tag and set its dynamic contents when you open the modal. Look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appended your html, so it's too late, you need to remove the html from `'#table'`, like so :

```
$('#html').empty()
```

and you need to do it before appending again

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting the table value using the table = '';

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a variable if you have initialized it's value from "var" keyword.
But in this case delete would work :

```
x = 20;
delete x;
console.log(x);
```

So, if you've used `var` keyword before table variable then just remove that keyword. It would work fine. Also you can do

```
table="";
```

to reset it's value.